# How to hide the ?id=URL by using rewrite function with htaccess?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

For example how to transform this url: 
http://example.com/folder/?id=http://url_of_the_image/image.jpg

to 
http://example.com/folder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect

```
http://example.com/folder/?id=.*.jpg
```

to

```
http://example.com/folder/
```

I am assuming you want to remove the querystring , you can use this in your root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=.+\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^/?folder/?$ http://example.com/folder/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Hmm, yes it works fine, but the function needed is not executed, maybe the rewrite function is not good for my case? i mean i need to execute the function related to the ?id=img_url and hide it from the url...